# Windows domain computer "roaming"

Tags: laptop, domain, windows-networking

So lets say i was setting up a network for a home situation in which 15+ people lived. the residents of the home could not afford to buy 15 computer so they bought ~8 or so laptops to be shared. if these computers were configured on a windows domain would it be possible so that no matter what computer you logged into your files/settings/programs would persist as if you were using the same computer? additionally what problems would this pose if one of these laptops were to be used outside the network of their home?

Answer (score 2):

It is called a roaming profile and is supported by  recent versions of Windows Server.  What version have you deployed?  More info will get you a better answer.